# API Call is working in POSTMAN but API call with generated code is not working

Tags: python, rest, postman

API call is working in postman but when I am using generated code, it is not working.

Generated code:

```
import requests

url = "http://services.example.com/rest/v2/verification"

payload = "{\r\n  \"startDate\": \"2000-12-25\",\r\n  \"endDate\": \"2000-12-31\",\r\n  \"format\": \"CSV\"\r\n}"
headers = {
    'authorization': "Bearer XXXXX",
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "XXX"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I have tried to execute after removing postman-token also but still getting below error:

```
{"message":"Internal Server Error: correlationId=V2-ee8fb1b098490b8665dd936e8472978b","type":"error","code":1}
```

Comment: Try this `payload = "{"startDate": "2000-12-25", "endDate": "2000-12-31", "format": "CSV}"`

Comment: The API expects json, but you're not sending json.  Use `json=payload` instead of `data=payload`.

Comment: I have tried both options but getting same error

Answer (score 1):

When using passing json data in `requests`, you can pass a dictionary instead of string.

You can try this:

```py
import requests
import json

url = "http://services.XXX.com/rest/v2/verification"

payload = "{\r\n  \"startDate\": \"2000-12-25\",\r\n  \"endDate\": \"2000-12-31\",\r\n  \"format\": \"CSV\"\r\n}"
headers = {
    'authorization': "Bearer XXXXX",
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "XXX"
    }

response = requests.post(url,json=json.loads(payload),headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: I have tried this also but still getting same error

Answer (score 1):

This could help. json.dumps() function will convert a subset of Python objects into a JSON string. So instead of sending a Python dictionary, you're passing in a JSON

```
payload = json.dumps({"startDate": "2000-12-25", "endDate": "2000-12-31",  "format":"CSV"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the payload variable, to a Json oblect this way:

Instead of:

```
payload = "{\r\n  \"startDate\": \"2000-12-25\",\r\n  \"endDate\": \"2000-12-31\",\r\n  \"format\": \"CSV\"\r\n}"
```

You can use:

```
payload = {"startDate": "2000-12-25", "endDate": "2000-12-31",  "format":"CSV"}
```

Comment: I have tried this also but still getting same error